# Entity Framework context "not freshed"?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, oracle11g

Platform: .net core 3.1 and Oracle 11g.

Here's my C# code snippet:

```
// this puts the value "00000000-0000-00" in ExtRef
// On the database end, there's a before-insert trigger that overwrites this value
newCustomer.ExtRef = Guid.Empty.ToString().Substring(0, 16);

using CustomerContext cntxt =
    new CustomerContext(connectionStrings[MySchema]);

cntxt.Customer.Add(newCustomer);
cntxt.SaveChanges();

Customer saved =
    cntxt.Customer
         .AsQueryable()
         .Where(customer => customer.Name1 == newCustomer.Name1)
         .Single();

// Though the database reflects a new value for the ExtRef, this call still returns 00000000-0000-00
output.WriteLine($"{saved.ExtRef}");
```

I tried with a new instance of the context and the ExtRef has the value in the database.  **Is there a way that I can get the updated ExtRef value without using the 2nd context?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to mark the ExtRef field in the entity as `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)`. This tells EF to expect the value to be set on insert, so you can read it after `SaveChanges`.

```
public class Customer
{
    // ... 

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public string ExtRef { get; set; } = "00000000-0000-00"; // Set a default here.
}
```

Then this should work as expected:

```
// newCustomer.ExtRef = Guid.Empty.ToString().Substring(0, 16); Not needed.

using CustomerContext cntxt = new CustomerContext(connectionStrings[MySchema])
{
    cntxt.Customer.Add(newCustomer);
    cntxt.SaveChanges();
}
output.WriteLine($"{newCustomer.ExtRef}");
```